# Midori faces error granting trust (Raspbian Stretch)

Tags: raspbian-stretch, web-browsers, midori

I am trying to install Midori on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, and I am struggling to access some addresses that Midori recognises as untrusted websites. When I click "trust this website", the browser shows the following error:

> Error granting trust: Couldn't find place to store the pinned
>   certificate
>
> *pkcs11:library-manufacturer=GNOME%20Keyring ,pkcs1:library-description=PKCS%2311%20Kit%20Trust%Module*

When one installs Midori, gnome keyring is installed as part of its dependencies.

I then made the following changes:

```
$ sudo find / -name gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
```

This yielded:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
```

Then:

```
sudo modutil -add gnome-keyring -libfile /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so -mechanisms RSA:DSA -dbdir ~/.config/midori/
```

At the end of this, a line indicating that the operation had been successful appeared.

**HOWEVER**, the same error occurred as quoted above when Midori was used both before and after a reboot.

**How can I fix this error?**

Comment: No key store is available or it's incorrectly setup. https://wiki.xfce.org/midori/faq

Comment: I followed all of these instructions, and the gnome-keyring was successfully located at the end of it, but I still got the same error above.